# does normal pointer arithmetic works on opencl kernels?

Tags: c, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

For example,does this snippet of code would compile and execute normally?

```
int* end = local_buffer + BUFFER_SIZE;
for(int* x = local_buffer; x < end; ++x)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, as long as the pointers are all in the device space. No issue.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer arithmetic does work, but you need to annotate your pointers with the appropriate memory space. So your example code is most likely wrong: if `local_buffer` is declared as

```
local int local_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

Then the `end` and `x` variables' types **must** also have the `local` specfier:

```
local int* end = …;
for (local int* x = …
```

The default is `global`, which will cause things to fail badly if your pointer is into local or constant memory. I've found that many OpenCL implementations don't warn you about this, so you have to be super careful.